# How to find the equation of circle that passes through ($5,3$) , ($7,-2$) and ($-4,4$) circle with center at origin ($0,0$) and radius $r$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, conic-sections

It is a challenge assignment on our class and I can't figure out how to solve it I always got stuck it is not the same as the other examples which are easy to solve. thanks

Comment: Are you sure the information given describes a circle? Because the distance from the points lying on the circle to the origin don't have the same radii.

Comment: Something is wrong with your problem.
A circle with (0, 0) as center passing through (5, 3) cannot possibly also pass through (7, -2)

Comment: our porfessor said that there is one cirlce in those points because it is not collinear.

Comment: Your professor is correct, but the circle can't have a center at $(0,0)$. It is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the equation for a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $r$ is $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2.$$Take any point, say $(5,3)$ and plug it into our equation and solve for $r$: $$(5)^2 + (3)^2 = 25 + 9 = 34 = r^2 \implies r = \sqrt{34}.$$ We need to verify this relationship with another point, say $(7,-2)$. So, $$(7)^2 + (-2)^2 = 49 + 4 = 53 = r^2 \implies r = \sqrt{53}$$ We have contradicting radii. So it is not possible for a circle to pass through all three of these points to be centered at the origin.

Comment: That's what I also think since I always having a problem halfway when solving it but our professor said that there is one circle on those points since it is not collinear.

Answer (score 0):

The three radii are different, so no  origin centered circle can be defined.